# Convergence criteria for series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I determine the convergence or divergence for the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\cos(\pi/n)\text{ and }\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5^n-2^n}{7^n-2^n}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one diverges, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigl|(-1)^n\cos\left(\frac\pi n\right)\bigr|=1\neq0$.

The second one converges, by the root test:$$\sqrt[n]{\frac{5^n-2^n}{7_n-2^n}}=\frac57\sqrt[n]{\frac{1-\left(\frac25\right)^n}{1-\left(\frac27\right)^n}}\to\frac57<1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Without any computation for the second, with *equivalence*: $\;5^n-2^n\sim_\infty 5^n$, $\;7^n-2^n\sim_\infty 5^n$, hence
$$\frac{5^n-2^n}{7^n-2^n}\sim_\infty\frac{5^n}{7^n}=\Bigl(\frac57\Bigr)^n,$$
which converges.

The same tools lets you prove in a very simple way that $\;\dfrac{5^n-3^n}{7^n-2^n}\;$ converges, for instance, which would be more complex with the *root test*.